# How to unfocus button after ajax form was rebuilt?

Tags: forms, ajax, 8

I have a form that is completely ajaxified and when I submit the form the submit button stays focused.

I have styling in place and it results in bad UX. How should I unfocus the button? Do I have to implement ajax response and some custom JS for this? Seems like a hacky solution :(

Comment: Do you have any code example ?

Comment: Had this issue several times in the past, not only with submit, but also with other form elements, never found the cause, only workarounds.

Comment: I think that this is caused by the fact that Drupal uses mousedown event and not click so the button never get's "unpressed" and when the form is rebuilt, and this is only my speculation, the DOM takes the new button as the old one, maybe, so it will be still active.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by setting focus to another element on rebuild.

I don't know how to do it in Drupal 8, but here's Drupal 7 code to focus an element:

**In the form_alter:**

```
  // Focus the first element on rebuild.
  if ($form_state['rebuild']) {
    $first_element = array_keys($form['entry_fieldset']['entry_ids'])[0];
    $form_state['focus_id'] = $first_element;
  }

  // Allow a form element to be focused.
  if (isset($form_state['focus_id'])) {
    // Pass the element ID as a variable to the JS.
    $settings = array('focus_id' => $form_state['focus_id']);
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = array(
      'data' => array('example' => $settings),
      'type' => 'setting',
    );
  }
```

**JS:**

```js
  /**
   * Focus a form element.
   */
  Drupal.behaviors.exampleFocusElement = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      if (settings.example && settings.example.focus_id) {
        // Focus the element having the ID passed in.
        $('#' + settings.example.focus_id, context).focus();
      }
    }
  };
```